# Is there any way to make this C++ program error free or I have to remove one of x declared in one the inherited class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, name-lookup, diamond-problem

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    A(){cout<<"Constructing A \n";}
    ~A(){cout<<"Destructinf A \n";}
    int x;
};
class B : virtual public A
{
    public:
    B(){cout<<"Constructing B \n";}
    ~B(){cout<<"Destructinf B \n";}
    int x=20;
};

class C : virtual public A
{
    public:
    C(){cout<<"Constructing C \n";}
    ~C(){cout<<"Destructinf C \n";}
    int x=50;



};

class D : public B,public C
{
    public:
        D(){cout<<"Constructing D \n";}
        ~D(){cout<<"Destructinf D \n";}
};

int main()
{
    D obj;
    obj.x; //x invoked
    cout<<obj.x<<"\n";  

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**
error: request for member ‘x’ is ambiguous

*Although I have used virtual class, still I am getting the above error.Do I have to remove One of the x declared in class B and Class C or is there any way to solve this error*

Comment: Why do `B` and `C` need a specific `x` member ? Why not use the one they get from `A` base class and assign it with the proper value ?

Comment: Yes use mixin/crtp not multiple inheritance to combine functionality. In my book diamond inheritance is a design problem and thus should be solved before you start coding. (eg. https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/12/12/mixin-classes-yang-crtp/)

Comment: The declarations of `x` on both child classes don't do what you think they do. They don't define the default value for `x` in `A`. That's not how C++ works.

Comment: okay that means I have to remove one of the x declared in of the class?

Comment: It is not clear which value do you actually expect `obj.x` to have ? `obj` is of type `D` which derives from both `B` and `C` and each of them seem to require a differnt value for `x`.

Answer (score 1):

The lookup set for the name `x` in the derived class `D` includes two names in its direct base classes `{ B::x, C::x }`. So using the unqualified name `x` in these statements

```
obj.x; //x invoked
cout<<obj.x<<"\n";
```

is ambiguous.

You could use qualified names like for example

```
D obj;
cout<<obj.B::x<<"\n";
cout<<obj.C::x<<"\n";
```

If you will remove the data member x in one of the base classes of the class `D` then there will be no ambiguity and you may write (for example if to remove the data member `x` in the class `B`)

```
D obj;
cout<<obj.x<<"\n";
cout<<obj.C::x<<"\n";
```

If you want tp have one data member with the name x then remove it from the both classes B and C as for example

```
class B : virtual public A
{
    public:
    B() { x = 20; cout<<"Constructing B \n";}
    ~B(){cout<<"Destructinf B \n";}
};

class C : virtual public A
{
    public:
    C(){ x = 50; cout<<"Constructing C \n";}
    ~C(){cout<<"Destructinf C \n";}
}
```

Pay attention to that the destructor should be declared as virtual.

Comment: Ok, now I got my answer .thanks everybody for your help.